# Adding vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, addition

I'm a C++ beginner and I'm trying to write a method which will take two vectors and add together their contents.

For example,
v1{1,2,3}+v2{2,4,6} should yield v3{3,6,9}.

Here's what my code looks like right now:

```
Vec Vec::operator+(const Vec& original){
    if(mySize != original.mySize){
    throw invalid_argument ("No!");
    }
    Item* sumVector = new Item(mySize);
    for(unsigned i=0; i<mySize; i++){
        sumVector[i] = myArray[i] + original.myArray[i];
    }
    return * sumVector;
}
```

However, this isn't working because my assertion v3.getItem(0) == 3 is failing.  I'm sure you already know this if you're answering this question but Vec is the name of one of my classes in this and Item  is a typedef double.

Comment: `sumVector` is a pointer (it doesn't need to be and it shouldn't be.) Think of what `operator[]` does when applied to a pointer.

Comment: Oh no memory leak operator! Why are you returning a newed object by value?

Comment: Hey welcome _@TheFaceOfBlue_! What about just using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), before starting to roll your own? There's a lot of obstacles and pitfalls to get it done right, and almost never is worth it, to come up with a proprietary implementation.

Comment: I would love to just use std::vector but this is for a class I'm taking (no pun intended) and I'm required to have my own class.

Comment: What is `Item`? How does it relate to `Vec`?

Comment: To follow up on the above -- your function claims to return a `Vec`, but it actually returns an `Item`. You never create a `Vec` in the function, so what is it supposed to return exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Shouldn't it use `Vec::Vec(Item)` and still return a `Vec`, assuming such a ctor exists?

Answer (score 2):

As juanchopanza mentioned in the comments, `sumVector` is a pointer.  Unfortunately for you, `operator[]` is defined for pointers, which may have given a confusing compile error for beginners.

For a solution that best retains the erroneous intent of the original code, this:

`sumVector[i] = myArray[i] + original.myArray[i];`

needs to be this:

`(*sumVector)[i] = myArray[i] + original.myArray[i];`

This way, you de-reference the pointer first, then access `operator[]` for the vector class.  This is really bad though, and probably not even a solution.

You must understand what your code is doing.  You are allocating a new array of `Items` on the **heap**, and then returning a copy of a `Vec` using the `*Item`, which is equivalent to `Item[0]`, as the `Vec`'s constructor.  Not only are you constructor a `Vec` with a single double input (without seeing your class declarations I can't know if this is a valid thing, but it probably isn't), but this heap allocation of `Items` will never have a corresponding free since you have lost the only reference to it when you leave the function scope.  You will never be able to free the memory, which means it is a memory leak.

The correct intent (I assume) is to create a local vector on the **stack** with computations, and then return it.  This means changing two lines:

```
Item* sumVector = new Item(mySize)
return * sumVector;
```

to

```
Vec sumVector(mySize); //now this is actually a vector
return sumVector;
```

Note that vector types usually just hold a pointer in their class type, in addition to some metadata.  This pointer value is allocated on the stack, and the pointer itself points to heap memory which the vector manages.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense.  I'm going to be honest though, all of this pointer and dereferencing stuff is still a little tricky for me to understand so I'll have to study up on that.

I made the edits you suggested but now I think my types are mismatched because I'm getting an error `invalid types 'Item {aka double}[unsigned int]' for array subscript` on `sumVector[i] = myArray[i] + original.myArray[i];` which I don't think makes sense because all three of those arguments are Item* except for sumVector which I just changed per your suggestion.

Sorry about this.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: oops I meant to change `Item` to `Vec`!  I'm assuming your vector has a constructor that takes in a size?

Answer (score -2):

Change this statement

```
Item* sumVector = new Item(mySize);
```

to

```
Item* sumVector = new Item[mySize];
```

And instead of

```
return * sumVector;
```

there shall be

```
return sumVector;
```

provided that class Vec has a constructor with parameter of type `Item *`
However in any case there is a problem with the constructor because even it has a parameter of type `Item *` it does not know how many elements were allocated.
So you have to create an object of type Vec inside the body of the operator.

Also it would be better to declare the operator as

```
Vec Vec::operator+(const Vec& original) const;
```

Comment: Ok, I did that and it's still not working.  Hmm... sorry about this.  I'm sure it's an easy fix but, as I said, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @TheFaceOfBoe I have added additional remark in my post about the constructor, You have to create an object of type Vec inside the body of operator because I do not know how the constructor will know how many elements of the array were allocated.